# ionic state go prevents side menu from being displayed

Tags: angular-ui-router, ionic-framework, ionic-view

I'm using the slide menu built in example in Ionic.
When I redirect the to the home page from any page (with $location or $state.go), the menu is disabled. 
It cannot be displayed any longer.

```
$state.go('app.home');
$location.path('/#/app/home');
```

Any idea what's happening?

Here's the menu template

```
<ion-side-menus>

    <ion-side-menu-content drag-content="true">
        <ion-nav-bar class="bar-dark">
            <ion-nav-back-button>
            </ion-nav-back-button>

            <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
                <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon" menu-toggle="left">
                </button>
            </ion-nav-buttons>
        </ion-nav-bar>

        <ion-nav-view name="menuContent"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-side-menu-content>

    <ion-side-menu side="left">
        <ion-header-bar class="bar-light">
        <h1 class="title">Title</h1>
        </ion-header-bar>
        <ion-content>
            <ion-list>
                <ion-item menu-close href="#/app/login">
                    Login
                </ion-item>
                <ion-item menu-close href="#/app/account">
                    Account
                </ion-item>
                <ion-item menu-close href="#/app/logout">
                    Logout
                </ion-item>
            </ion-list>
        </ion-content>
    </ion-side-menu>

</ion-side-menus>
```

And this is the config of the app

```
$stateProvider

        .state('app', {
            url: "/app",
            abstract: true,
            templateUrl: "templates/menu.html"
        })

        .state('app.home', {
            url: "/home",
            views: {
                'menuContent@app': {
                    templateUrl: "modules/home/views/home.html",
                    controller: 'HomeCtrl'
                }
            }
        });

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app/home');
```

Comment: what would you be looking for? I'm in the LoginCtrl, I do state.go('app.home'). There's nothing in HomeCtrl, just a log message. The only I should have mentioned is that the 1st screen when you launch the app is app.home thanks to $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app/home'); and the left menu is displayable there...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

answer here [ionic slide menu don't appear when i use state.go in my controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29654358/ionic-slide-menu-dont-appear-when-i-use-state-go-in-my-controller)

I forgot to use the option `enable-menu-with-back-views="true"` on my `<ion-side-menus>`

Answer (score 0):

```
    .state('login', {
      url: "/login",
      templateUrl: "templates/login.html",
      controller: 'AppCtrl'
    })

    .state('app', {
      url: "/app",
      abstract: true,
      templateUrl: "templates/menu.html",
      controller: 'AppCtrl',
      onEnter: function($state, Auth) {
        if (!Auth.isLoggedIn()) {
          $state.go('login');
        }
      }
    })

   .state('app.Propertylist', {
      url: "/Propertylist",
      views: {
        'menuContent': {
          templateUrl: "templates/Propertylist.html",
          controller: 'PropertyCtrl',
          onEnter: function($state, Auth) {
            if (!Auth.isLoggedIn()) {
              $state.go('login');
            }
          }
        }
      }
    })`enter code here`
```

Comment: What are you saying? Redirection from inside a controller should not work as I expect and thus should be done from the .config ?